# Encrypting a parameter with openssl

Tags: security, encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt a parameter with openssl using public.key and decrypt with private.key using linux command line. But the requirement is that the output after encryption should be just in one line so that I can transfer it or send it over to other server. File creation as output is not required.

I have seen rsautl but it gives output in a file or hex dump, which is not possible in my case as I require the output in one line. Please provide the necessary help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pkeyutl` sends its output to a file only if you ask for it. If you do not specify an output file (with the `-out` option) it sends its output to the standard output. But as it is binary, you cannot easily manipulate it and, moreover, it could be that there are end-of-lines in the output stream.

In order to solve this you can pipe the output of `pkeyutl` to `base64`. If your version of `base64` wraps its output you'll have to concatenate to get the result on one line only. Some versions (e.g. `GNU coreutils 8.10`) have a `-w0` option that prevents wrapping and produces a single line output (without end-of-line). Example with `openssl` version `1.0.2a`:

```
echo "foo" | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey bob_id_rsa.pub | base64 -w0
```

where `bob_id_rsa.pub` is bob's public key in `openssl` format. You can decrypt with:

```
base64 -d | openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey bob_id_rsa
```

where `bob_id_rsa` is bob's private key. Complete example with encryption followed by decryption:

```
bar=$( echo foo | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey bob_id_rsa.pub | base64 -w0 )
cue=$( echo $bar | base64 -d | openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey bob_id_rsa )
echo $cue
foo
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. I was able to decrypt also. Can you please guide how can I use public key to encrypt and private key to decrypt if I am using the above command ?

Comment: Sure. You will need the public key (`bob_id_rsa.pub` in my answer) in `openssl` format. In case you have a SSH private key, you can easily extract the public key in `openssl` format from it with: `openssl rsa -in bob_id_rsa -pubout -out bob_id_rsa.pub`. Then, you encrypt with: `openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey bob_id_rsa.pub | base64 -w0` and you decrypt with: `base64 -d | openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey bob_id_rsa`. Complete example: `echo "foo" | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey bob_id_rsa.pub | base64 -w0 | base64 -d | openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey bob_id_rsa`.